# Changing the text of the cancel button of an NSOpenPanel (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsopenpanel

I would like to have a customizable chooser where many features may be customized.  One thing I cannot figure out how to do is change the text of the cancel button.  I found that the method setPrompt will change the text of the okay button but I can find no similar method for the cancel button, is there such a method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn’t a built-in method for it, but you could try iterating through the panel’s content view’s subviews and looking for the button whose action is `cancel:`, and calling `setTitle:` on that.

Update: There's a private `_setCancelButtonTitle:` method, also.

(Also, both of these will probably break in a sandboxed app.)

Comment: Kind of gnarley but it works, thanks!  You actually have to look at the subviews of the views of the contentview to find the buttons, but sure enough it worked.

Comment: Would you be able to share some code - "iterating through the panel's content view's subviews". I've tried and it's not succeeding. I'm picking up [[panel contentView] subviews] - however it appears to have no content. I have created a panel via [NSOpenPanel openPanel] and subsequently use [panel beginWithCOmpletionHandler...] - I'm wondering if the view hierarchy has not loaded at the point I'm trying to walk through the subviews. I'm trying to change the keyEquivalent on the OK button.

Answer (score 1):

The setPrompt: method in NSSavePanel (super class of NSOpenPanel) will do the job for you.